# jq - not working as expected in Jenkins shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jq

I have the following JSON named as *my.json*.

```
[
  {
    "action": "copy",
    "artifact_location": "one foo one"
  },
  {
    "action": "copy",
    "artifact_location": "one bar one"
  },
  {
    "action": "remove",
    "artifact_location": "two foo two"
  }
]
```

My goal is to delete ***all*** the objects in the root JSON array if the ***artifact_location*** property of the a object contains the string value ***"foo"***.

I'm using [jq command line utility](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to accomplish this task.
Following is my *jq* command. It is working perfectly when I'm running it on my local machine (*macOS and jq version is 1.6*).

```
jq 'del(.[] | select(.artifact_location | test("foo")))' my.json
```

However, the above commands gives the following error when I try to run it as a shell script in a Jenkins job(*Ubuntu and jq version is 1.3*).

```
error: test is not defined
del(.[] | select(.artifact_location | test("foo")))
                                      ^^^^
1 compile error
```

What am I possibly doing wrong here?

Comment: I'd say upgrade to a supported and maintained distribution for this Jenkins machine. jq 1.3 date back from Ubuntu Trusty Tahr that is **E**nd **O**f **L**ife since 2019-04-25. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOL#Ubuntu_14.04_Trusty_Tahr **This Jenkins server is not even getting security updates any-more!**

Comment: What Lea said above my comment. If you have to do this with jq 1.3 though, use `contains` instead of `test`.

Comment: Upgrading the jq version in Jenkins is not an option unfortunately.
Greatly appreciate if you provide an example of how the contains() function can be used in such use-case.

Comment: @gayashanbc The most straightforward replacement there, is a 1 for 1 replacement: `jq 'del(.[] | select(.artifact_location | contains("foo")))' my.json`

Comment: @Léa Gris I tried that query. But it only deletes the artifact_location property from all the matching objects instead of deleting the whole object.

Comment: @gayashanbc try this with deleting the parent object instead, as jq 1.3 seems to behave differently than jq 1.6 or newer: `jq 'del(.[] | select(.artifact_location | contains("foo")) | ..)' my.json`

Comment: @Léa Gris Double period notation is also giving a compilation error in jq 1.3.
The alternative approach suggested by Jeff Mercado below using the map function solved my issue. Thanks a lot for helping out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`test/0`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#test(val),test(regex;flags)) is for testing if a string matches a particular regular expression, which is not available in jq 1.3 (as mentioned in the comments). [`contains/1`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.3/#contains) could be used in this case.

```
del(.[] | select(.artifact_location | contains("foo")))
```

I would rather approach this as filtering out the objects, rather than deleting them. Select objects that does not contain "foo".

```
map(select(.artifact_location | contains("foo") | not))
```